# Powershell - Exclude Sub-Folders In Folder From Being Deleted Based on Array Values

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I have a list of array values returned from a PHP script in my PowerShell executable.  These values correspond to active projects on my Windows Server.  I have a projects folder in my `C:/` drive that has a sub-folder for each project that has been processed by that server.  The structure looks something like this:

```
/project-files
    /1
    /2
    /3
    /4
```

The above signals that the server has processed four projects so far.

I run a Scheduled Task Powershell script that cleans out the `project-files` folder every day.  When I run my script, I only want to delete sub-folders that correspond to projects that are not currently running on the server.

I have the following Powershell:

```
$active_projects = php c:/path/to/php/script/active_projects.php
if($active_projects -ne "No active projects"){
    # Convert the returned value from JSON to an Powershell array
    $active_projects = $active_projects | ConvertFrom-Json
    # Delete sub folders from projects folder
    Get-ChildItem -Path "c:\project-files\ -Recurse -Force |
    Select -ExpandProperty FullName |
    Where {$_ -notlike 'C:\project-files\every value in $active_projects*'}
    Remove-Item -Force
}
```

I want to exclude sub-folders within the `project-files` folder from being deleted if the sub-folder number corresponds to a project number in the `$active_projects` array.

How would I go about writing the `Where` statement here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the [`-notcontains`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847759.aspx) operator to see if each project is listed as an active project. In the following, I have made the assumption that the JSON string from your PHP script returns a list of strings.

```
$active_projects = php c:/path/to/php/script/active_projects.php

if ($active_projects -ne "No active projects") {

  # Convert the returned value from JSON to a PowerShell array
  $active_projects = $active_projects | ConvertFrom-Json

  # Go through each project folder
  foreach ($project in Get-ChildItem C:\project-files) {

    # Test if the current project isn't in the list of active projects
    if ($active_projects -notcontains $project) {

      # Remove the project since it wasn't listed as an active project
      Remove-Item -Recurse -Force $project
    }  
  }
}
```

If however your JSON array is a list of integers, then the test line should instead be:

```
    if ($active_projects -notcontains ([int] $project.Name)) {
```

Comment: `$active_projects` is an array list of integers.  However, if I do the `[int] $project` conversion, I get an `"Cannot convert the "373" value of type System.IO.DirectoryInfo" to type "System.Int32"` error.  If don't do the conversion, all the sub-folders - including those related to active projects - fall within the if conditional.  I did a couple of `Write-Hosts` around the conditional and it seems the values are correct.  Could `-notcontains` be not catching my active projects because they are of different types?

Comment: No, I got that bit wrong as it should be `$project.Name`! I've amended the answer.